# Add a bit column for whether a badge is retired in SEDE or a RetiredDate column

Tags: feature-request, badges, data-explorer

It would be nice (for example) to be able to easily filter out badges that are retired when querying SEDE for analysis purposes.

A bit for it would work, or alternatively, a nullable `RetiredDate`.

Or did I just miss something and this is already possible / supported?